# Making table in html with different column height based on the length of data

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue here. How can I make a table in html with two different column heights depending on the length of data in it. Can I use div for this purpose? I want the layout to move from top to bottom instead of left to right.I am attaching the images as an example.

[image]

[image]

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Don't use a table at all. Use floats or flexbox.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/zp1q2e88/

Comment: Actually i do not want to show the extra/empty space as well. I want to fill the data there. http://osvaldas.info/examples/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback/

Comment: Thanks!! it worked (Y)

Comment: @Nosheen m posting as answer plz accept as answer..thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your target, you can make 2 div in one parent div and then use fix width as you want dynamic height. M giving border to show you the height for different different div according to their content.

Also don't forget to use `clear:both` after using **Float** or else there will be white space.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zp1q2e88/) you can change the div structure according to your need :)

Comment: @Himechi90, thanx and yes op said in comment that it work so waiting ..:)

Answer (score 0):

Please use following HTML code for the same

```
<style type="text/css">

.main-cont{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.left-cont{
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}
.right-cont{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

</style>


<div class="main-cont">
<div class="left-cont">
Burgers<br>
 mode with premium angus beef:  substitute grilled chicken breast or block-bean veggie burger
 <br><br>
Classic Burger $7.95 Our not-so-basic burger topped with lettuce: tomato and shoved red onions
 <br><br>
Hickory Burger $8.95 Cheddar cheese. hickory-smoked bacon and smoky barbecue sauce
 <br><br>

</div>
<div class="right-cont">
Hot Dogs premium Vienna beef hot dogs: substitute TofuPup for no charge   <br><br>
Chicago Style $3.75 Topped with yellow mustard: green relish: onions: tomatoes: pickles: sport peppers and celery salt <br><br>
Sonoran Dog $4.50 Wrapped in bacon and grilled: topped with tomatoes: onions, cotijo cheese, pinto beans, and hot sauce  <br><br>

</div>

</div>
```